# Modify params(query) from Grid Paging next button

Tags: button, extjs, grid, paging

I'm having some paging issues when I wan't to display the next page with the "next button" from m paging toolbar.

I'm using a form search to display data in my grid, which send along "start" and "limit" params a query (my search more precisely).

```
listeners: {
    keyup: function(el,type){
        var searchQuery = el.getValue();      //Get the value from the textfield 
        store.load({
            params: {
                start: 0,
                limit: 5,
                query: searchQuery
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Let's say I was searching for "Apple", the server side script is called like this :

> serverSideScript.jsp?query=Apple&start=0&limit=5

So now, the problem is that the next button only send start & limit. Where can I overwrite the load method used by all paging buttons in order to add my personal param.

Thanks in advance for your help.
TheRainFall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `beforeload` listener of the store to fetch any required data and add it to parameters

```
beforeload: function(store) {
  store.baseParams.query = getSearchQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition Mchl, I am going to check this out. By the way, I tried to implement a "live search" which means that my load method is only used in my FormPanel. I wanted to fetch my grid only when searching. (I have edited the code above)